# Class inheritance in more than one file c++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to make a big class of constances called "Adresy". One .h file isn't enought.

```
my adresy.h looking like:
#include <Windows.h>
#ifndef __Adresy_H_
#define __Adresy_H_

class Adresy {
    public:
//first part of constances...
};
#endif
```

I want to add extening to this class in second file (for example adresy2.h):

```
#include "adresy.h"
class Items: public Adresy {
    public:
/// NEXT CONSTANCSES
};
```

How should look second class and how to combine them into one file to including (i don't want to include for example 5 files extending one class)?

Comment: I don't know how your second class should look, since you didn't say what either of your classes do. But, you can include the second header file at the end of the first header file so that users of you classes only have one header file to include.

Comment: If the classes are small and directly belong to each other, there's nothing wrong with just declaring them in the same header file.

Comment: but this class will be very big..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand your issue as:

1. one header file for including: **adresy,h**
2. this file shall contain class Adresy which has so many entries that it is too many for one file.

I'd suggest this solution:

**adresy.h**

```
#include "ext/adresy_part1.h"
#include "ext/adresy_part2.h"
#include "ext/adresy_part3.h"

class Adresy : public Adresy1, public Adresy2, public Adresy3 {
};
```

**ext/adresy_part1.h**

```
class Adresy1 {
public:
   // first bunch of constants
};
```

And so on for as many parts as you need.
As you can see - I suggest also to put these extra files to separate directory `ext`.

Comment: Just use `Adresy::xyz`. All public entries from public base classes are visible in the derived class, unless derived define an entry with the same name. If your `Adresy` has empty body `{}` then, as I said, you can use `Adresy::xyz`. Please don't forget to upvote and accept if you find this answer useful.

Comment: And, if it happens that you have two members of the same name - like `Adresy1::xyz` and `Adresy2::xyz` - then you need to use explicit base class name: `Adresy1::xyz` or `Adresy2::xyz`. `Adresy::xyz` would be ambiguous. I believe you are avoiding such cases.